# How can I hide or make space between the add component button and other custom buttons in editor script in the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(AddCameras))]
public class Cameras : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        AddCameras myScript = (AddCameras)target;
        if (GUILayout.Button("Add Cameras"))
        {
            myScript.Add();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried also to remove the line

```
DrawDefaultInspector();
```

but the result is the same :

The custom button Add Cameras is too close to the default Add Component button and it's confusing and too close to each other.

[image: buttons too close]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [GUILayout.Space](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.Space.html)

You can specify the amount of pixels you want to space by.

```
GUILayout.Space(10); // <- will add a space of 10 pixels.
```

There is also the EditorGUILayout class, which also has a [Space()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Space.html) function, that adds a predefined space.

```
EditorGUILayout.Space(); // <- will add a predefined amount of space
```

In general the GUILayout and EditorGUILayout classes have a lot of nifty helpers which make editor drawing much less tedious.